# iPhone - Sprite Not Showing Up Because Background is Hiding It

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, sprite

I have a sprite that is hidden behind a background image. How can I make the sprite go to the front? Code answers would be great.

Comment: You do this by setting a node’s zPosition property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As sangony said, this can be done through the node's zPosition property.

For example, if the background node is called 'bgNode' and the sprite is 'spriteNode'

```
bgNode.zPosition = 0;
spriteNode.zPosition = 1;
```

This will render the spriteNode over top of the bgNode.  This is assuming they share the same parent node.